# Authorization. Dropbox. Cordova

Tags: cordova, authorization, dropbox

Several weeks, trying to deal with how to connect to dropbox  and myself application. I create an application in dropbokse, and connect to him. When logging arise the window where I was asked to confirm the possibility of using files. I click to allow (in the annex to dropbokse Development users increased by 1), but this box does not disappear and not close, and does not go authorization. Has downloaded here's an example: https://github.com/donovan-graham/cordova_oauth. The situation is exactly the same. But in this case clearly shows that the authorization is no error, but just everything is hang. (But then again, if previously reset Development users, then when it fails, logging, it still increases by 1)

Answer (score 1):

May not answer your question directly, but this could help.

You can use the [Dropbox HTTP API](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/documentation/http/documentation) to link your Cordova app with `http` requests. In my app I used these `http` requests to link it to Dropbox since there is no official Dropbox JavaScript Documentation at the moment.

In order to begin the Dropbox Authentication you should get your users to navigate to https://www.dropbox.com/oath2/authorise . This can be easily done within your application by using `cordova-plugin-inappbrowser`.

**example**

```
var response_type = 'code';
var client_id = '<your-dropbox_app_client_id>';
var redirect_uri = 'https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/redirect_receiver';
var data = 'response_type=' + response_type + '&client_id=' + client_id + '&redirect_uri=' + redirect_uri';

var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(
  'https://www.dropbox.com/oauth2/authorize?' + data', 
  '_blank',
  'location=no,clearcache=yes'
);

ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) {
  // get the response from event.url
  var code = event.url.substring(redirect_uri.length + 6);

  var headers = new Headers();
  headers.append('Authorization', 'Basic <your basic auth here>');
  headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

  var request = `code=${code}&grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=${redirect_uri}`;
  var observable = http.post('https://api.dropboxapi.com/oauth2/token', request, { headers: headers });

  // the data returned will have the access_token that will link Dropbox to your App!!
});
```

**Some notes**
This example is within a cordova app built with Angular2. Thus, the `http` module returns observables. You could just as easily perform these steps with `$.ajax` in jQuery or similar.

We use `https://www.dropbox.com/1/oauth2/redirect_receiver` as the redirect_url because it must be a `https` connection and there our `access_token` will be sent. You must ensure that this `url` has been entered into your allowed redirect urls in your dropbox-app page!

Lastly, your `<basic-auth-here>` is basic http authentication with your dropbox-app's app-key and secret-key.

Good luck!